# How to move a single new file to a new branch in git

Tags: git

I have one new staged file A on branch branch_A. There are some changes in other files as well on branch_A.

I want to create a new branch - branch_B and move file A to branch_B without moving changes in other files on branch_A.

Is that possible? If so - how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge)

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate. There is only one answer there (6-th from the top) that answers my question and this is by a coincidence. Moreover - OP asked quite a different question. If you still insist - feel free to do whatever you want with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating the new brunch

```
git branch branch_B
```

Then move the file using `git stash`. 
if you want to stash a single file you can do the following:

```
git add myFileToMove
git stash --keep-index
```

If you have not made the commit yet, just run git stash. This will save away all of your changes. Switch to branch_B and run `git stash pop`.