# Git Merge only single file from master into current branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have just started using git. I created branch-A from master. I have created the file abc.txt in branch-A and merged branch-A into master successfully.
Now I am working same file in branch-A and want to merge master's (which abc.txt) file into branch-A (abc.txt) file.
I tried "git checkout master abc.txt" but it replaces branch-A file with master's abc.txt.

I know "git merge master" will do the work, but if someone can show me how to merge single file ONLY into current branch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: thats not a duplicate. he is asking about merging a single file not a single commit

Comment: @LazyBadger please reopen; this is not a duplicate. It's about the very specific case of doing a pseudo-merge of a single file from another commit.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, make sure your working directory is clean.

Then as you've discovered...

```
git checkout master abc.txt
```

...will replace the whole file, but what you might not have realized is that now you could make a patch from those differences if you reset. So *after* checking out the file:

```
git reset --mixed
git add --patch abc.txt
```

Now you can selectively choose the changes you want to include, commit, and then reset hard to arrive at that final state by discarding the unwanted differences.

```
git commit -m "merge changes to abc.txt"
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your answer. So you are saying I should start with:
1- git reset
2- git add -p abc.txt 

Do I need to "git checkout master abc.txt" first?

Comment: @AliHussainKhan yes, `checkout` the file first, then you will notice that it's been staged, but not committed. So if you `reset --mixed` this will keep all the changes in your working directory and you'll be able to `add --patch`

Comment: Actually you don’t need the working tree to be clean. Just commit the one file so you can reset it in the second step.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you only want this single file to be included in `branch-A`?
It sounds to me more like you want to do a rebase of `branch-A` on top of `master`, so all changes that have happened on `master` will be included in `branch-A`.

Here's the documentation for rebasing: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Basically, it will take you from:

```
      A---B---C branch-A
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

to

```
              A'--B'--C' branch-A
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

by checking out `branch-A` and calling

`git rebase master`

This means that whatever changes happened to `abc.txt` in commits E, F and G on master will be reflected in your commits on `branch-A`.

Rebase simply checks out `master` and applies the commits from `branch-A` one by one.

Comment: Thanks @Mathew for your answer. Yes there is a reason. When I create pull request I see conflicts and I want to resolve it by merging the same ONLY into my branch not whole master branch into my branch.

Comment: From my understanding of git, it is not possible to take the changes made to one file on another branch and apply them to your current branch.
If you do a rebase like I've described, you will be forced to resolve any conflicts along the way. Then when you create your pull request, there should be no conflicts.
The chances are you will just want to call `git checkout --ours abc.text` if a conflict appears to ensure that you take the changes made to the file on the master branch.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But I don't want to include other files into my branch from master except abc.txt

Comment: But when you merge in to master, you're going to end up with those other changes anyway - why would you not want them now so you can ensure nothing is going to break?

Comment: Lets say, there is another branch called "middle" which I use to do QA testing and after QA testing passed I create pull request to master. Now there is a scenario that my work is ready for QA testing and I want to create pull request to "middle" branch and found conflict in one file xyz.txt. Now I don't want to merge whole "middle" branch into my branch but xyz.txt file. Thats why I was looking for a solution to fetch and merge single file