# Git: How to pull only a subset of Dev branch into Master

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I need to pull a subset of files from my dev branch into Master. I am new to Git, and I am using it inside of VS2015 (VSTS). I want to pull 4 of 7 from dev into master but I am lost as to how.

Can I do it through the GUI, do I need to go to the command line?

Answer (score 1):

For fine-grained operations like that, it is best to revert to the [Git command-line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/command-prompt) (even for [VSTS: Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/)) and follow some of the options of "[How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449541/6309)".

In your case, since we are talking about only 4 files:

```
git checkout master
git checkout dev -- <paths>...
```

Or to selectively merge hunks

```
git checkout -p dev -- <paths>...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about moving certain commits.

```
git checkout master
git fetch 
git cherry-pick <coma separated commit-hashes>
git push origin master
```

If certain files

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git checkout -m <revision> <yourfilepath>
git add <yourfilepath>
git commit
```