# get specific stuff from master while working on a branch

Tags: git

I´m working in a branch and I changed the structure of the project. If people make some changes to the master, how can I bring those changes to the my branch without messing up my change structure.

Comment: What kinds of changes are you expecting? Changes to existing files? New files? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to merge `master` into your change branch:

```
git checkout change
git merge master
```

Changes made to existing files will automagically apply to the files in their new directories, possibly with merge conflicts if you've made changes on the same lines of those files.

You will need to move new files manually and make a new commit.

Comment: One minor gotcha is that in the event of major conflicts, both their version in yours can end up in their original locations and need to be resolved in a more manual way. I've only had this happen a couple of times, but it throws me every time it does.

Answer (score 1):

**git-merge** - Join two or more development histories together.

For More details enter in terminal `$man git-merge`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the following two branches where each letter represents a commit hash:

```
      C---------D    feature
     /
A---B---E---F---H    master
```

While you're working on the `feature` branch, it is a good idea to keep it in sync with `master` so that you reduce the amount of merge conflicts when you eventually create a Pull Request into `master`.

---

To keep the `feature` branch in sync, you have a few options:

#### 1. Adding all commits from `master` to `feature`:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

Example: If you are at commit `D` on the `feature` branch and you run above commands, you will apply commit `E`, `F` and `H` to the feature branch.

> Read more about it here: [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

#### 2. Adding only specific commits from `master` to `feature`

```
git checkout feature
git cheery-pick <commit-hash>
```

Example: Running `git cherry-pick F` will only add commit `F` to your `feature` branch.

> Read more about it here: [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

#### 3. Adding only specific files from `master` to `feature`

```
git checkout master <path/to/filename>
```

Example: Running `git checkout master src/index.js` will add the `index.js` file from commit `H` to your `feature` branch.

If you like to add the `index.js` from commit `F` instead, you can use the following commands:

```
git checkout master~1 src/index.js
```

or

```
git checkout <commit-hash> <path/to/filename>
```

> Read more about the command: [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

#### 4. Adding only specific lines of a file from `master` to `feature`

```
git checkout master <path/to/filename> -p
```

Example: If you run `git checkout master src/index.js --patch` you can decide which hunks of the `src/index.js` file from commit `H` you want to add to the `feature` branch.

---

I mostly use option 1. and 2. to sync my branches - sometimes also 3. Of course, there are many other ways of achieving the same with git, you can also have a look [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-to-selectively-merge-or-pick-changes-from-another-branch-in-git) for some alternatives.

Comment: This is a very thorough explanation of the options. Note that in steps 3 and 4, the OP will also need to do a `git add` and `git commit` (or `git commit -a`). A fifth option is `git rebase`.