# Merge from trunk to branch but only files in the branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, git-branch

I have branched off trunk to a feature branch. In order to keep my branch up to date, I would like to frequently merge back from trunk (always up to date), but I don't like everything in trunk getting merged into my branch.

Is it possible to somehow merge from trunk only the files I have in the branch?

E.g, before merge:

```
Trunk
  File 1
  File 2
  File 3
  File 4
Branch
  File 2
  File 3
```

After merge, I have the following, which I don't want. I want to only merge File 2 and File 3 from trunk.

```
Branch
  File 1
  File 2
  File 3
  File 4
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/449632/3879644

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff trunk
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=A @ | xargs -0 git rm -f
git commit
```

Comment: This somehow looks good, but could you please explain what this does, in steps?

Comment: It's exactly what it looks like: do the merge without committing, make a list of added files, remove everything on that list, then commit the result.

Comment: I still get over 100 changes staged for commit when I should have about 20.

Comment: Sounds like a good subject for a SO question, put together the evidence you're looking at, figure out where it differs from what you expect, ping me in a comment if you like.

Comment: I think this is because I get modified files after the initial merge from dev, and your iterator using `diff-filter=A`. Maybe I must just step back and take a second look at how I'm working. I was under the problem impression that "files in my branch" are only files I have modified since branching, and looking for a way to merge only those files and new files back from trunk.

Answer (score 5):

Augmenting @jthill's approach, I would do

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff trunk
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=A @ | xargs -0 git rm -f
rm .git/MERGE_*
git commit
```

This would make git forget that it's doing a merge and would prevent files from being deleted when you finally want to merge back into your trunk.

As a comment though, this is not a very sustainable workflow, even if you write your own script to automatically do this every time. It's worth asking the question of why you feel like you need to do this.

It might be that:
 - The repo is too large -- Then you should think about splitting up the code
 - Your work is logically separate -- Then you should definitely think about splitting up the code
 - There is broken work in trunk -- Then you should implement a new workflow that doesn't merge broken code into trunk

Alternative solutions if you don't want to modify your workflow would be to:

If you want to overwrite the changes completely

```
git checkout trunk -- *
git commit
```

If you want to completely overwrite some files

```
git checkout trunk -- file2
git commit
```

Or, interactive rebase gives you the option to only select the commts you want. This also won't result in files being deleted later on

```
git rebase -i trunk
```

Personally, I'd look into changing your workflow. If you have more information on your situation, we'd be able to help you figure out other solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I had to give the first answer I tried the bounty, but have a vote on me.