# branch A merge into B wihtout deleting file B that not exist in A

Tags: git, merge, branch

How can we merge two branches A and B when:
In branch A we have a file named **file1.py**:

```
print('file1')
print('branch A')
```

In branch B we have a file named **file1.py**:

```
print('file1')
print('branch B')
```

And a file named **file2.py**:

```
print('file2')
```

the result I would like to have is a branch B like this:
**file1.py**

```
print('file1.py')
print('branch A')
```

**file2.py**:

```
print('file2')
```

Its like a merge A -> B wihtout touching file existing in B that not exist in A.

Comment: `git checkout B` then `git merge A` should do. If there is any merge conflict just solve it by keeping the `A branch` version.

Comment: I just try and the result is just the file1.py, but the file2.py is deleting without merge conflict.

Comment: So file2.py gets deleted when you merge A into B? I recommend you to check this link https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Git-merge-deleting-files-while-merging/qaq-p/1115985 . Might be because you had file2.py in A.

Answer (score 1):

The key item you're missing here is that `git merge` does not *just* combine branch-A and branch-B.  In fact, before we can define *combine*, or even *branch*, we have to step back and consider what Git really does.

You might think that Git stores files in branches, but that's not right, and it still leaves you with the problem of defining the word *branch*.  What, exactly, is a "branch"?  Does Git store branches?  It's clear from your question wording that you don't really know what a branch is—but that's OK, a lot of Git users don't!  They have all kinds of trouble with Git too.  We need a solid foundation before we can build a house or skyscraper, so let's start with *commits*.

#### Git stores commits

Git's reason for existence, and its basic unit of storage when you're working with Git, is the *commit*.  So you need to know what a commit is and does for you.  Each commit:

- Is numbered: a commit has a unique global (or universal) ID—a GUID or UUID—which Git calls a *hash ID* or *object ID* (abbreviated *OID* ).  When you make a new commit, it gets a new, unique ID, unique across *every* Git repository.  That hash ID can never be used for any other commit.  That's why commit hash IDs are so big and ugly.  In fact, these numbers are impossible for humans to work with (other than by cut-and-paste or similar), so we don't normally use them directly.
- Is read-only: once you make a commit, it is frozen for all time.  (The numbering trick—the hashing scheme—that Git uses depends on this.)
- Contains two things: a *full snapshot of every file*, and some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself, such as your name and email address and a date-and-time-stamp.

The snapshots in the commit are themselves read-only, and the files are compressed, Git-ified, and—important for many reasons, including to keep the repository size under control—*de-duplicated*.  So when you make a new snapshot—a new commit—that mostly re-uses the files from an earlier commit, it hardly takes any space for those new files, as most of them *are* the old files.  But this does mean that these files are *entirely useless for getting new work done*, because to do *new* work, you need:

- files that every program, not just Git, can read; and
- files that programs can *modify or replace*.

So you won't actually do any work with the files that are stored *inside the commits*.  We'll come back to this in a moment.

Meanwhile, the metadata in each commit include more than just your name and email address.  Git adds, for its own purposes, a *list of previous commit hash IDs* into each commit's metadata.  This list *usually* has just one entry.  That one entry is the commit's *parent*.

The parent of a commit is how Git stores history.  The history in a repository is simply the set of *commits* in the repository.  We start at the end, with the *latest* commit, which has some big ugly hash ID: let's call that commit `H` (for Hash), although real hash IDs are things like [<sup><sub>`5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5) (you can see why humans don't use these things!).  Let's draw commit `H` as a letter with an arrow sticking out of it, pointing backwards:

```
            <-H
```

That's a representation of the *last* commit.  Commit `H` stores, in its metadata, the raw hash ID of its parent: the commit that comes *just before* `H`.  Let's call that commit `G` and draw *it* in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Commit `G`, of course, has a snapshot and metadata too, and its metadata contains the raw hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, which has a snapshot and metadata, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This is our chain of commits.  It ends at our latest commit `H`.  We must give Git the hash ID `H` so that Git can *find* commit `H`, but once we do that, Git will use the snapshot in `H` for the snapshot and the metadata in `H` for the parent, and can find commit `G` on its own.  Git can then use the snapshot and metadata and work its way back to `F` on its own, and from there, work back to `E`, `D`, and so on—all the way back to the very first commit (presumably commit `A`).

What will make Git *stop* going backwards is that `A` will have an *empty list of parent commit hash IDs*, so that `A` simply doesn't point backwards at all.  So the first commit ever in any given repository is slightly special: it doesn't point backwards to an earlier commit, meaning there is no earlier commit.

(Note that when we *clone* a repository, we *copy all the commits*.  Since they're exact copies, they have the *same hash ID*, and our Git software can easily tell, by comparing hash IDs, that our commit `H` is *the same* commit we got when we cloned *their* commit `H`: the hash IDs will match.  This is how two Git repositories *share* commits later: by comparing hash IDs.  They need not look at anything else, because the hash IDs are GUIDs.)

#### Branch names *find* commits

Now, as humans, we're bad at hash IDs.  We *could* write them down, or save them in files, or something, but we have a computer: why not have the *computer* save the latest hash ID `H` somewhere?  And that's the first thing a branch name is and does for us:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Here, the *branch name* `main` holds just the one hash ID `H`.  That's our *latest* commit, so it's the one we want to find *quickly*, and we can: we just tell Git "get me `main`" and that means "get me commit `H`".

We can create *new branch names* any time we like.  Note that our branch names, in our repository, are *our* names—they're not anyone else's branch names!—and we can create and destroy branch names whenever we feel like doing that, or change them to any spelling we like, as long as they meet Git's "branch name" qualities.  But I like to use the *same* branch names—or at least, mostly the same—in my repository as there are in the repository I cloned to *make* my repository.  So we may try not to just create random profusions of names.  *Git* won't care—Git only cares about the *commits*—but we might confuse ourselves if we go overboard.

Anyway, given:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

let's create two new branch names, `br-A` and `br-B`.  In Git, a branch name *must* point to some particular commit.  The usual choice is "the current commit", which—since we're initially using our branch name `main`—is commit `H`, the *latest* `main` commit.  So now we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- br-A, br-B, main
```

We now need a way, in our drawing, to show *which name we're using*.  Let's attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase, to just one of these three branch names, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- br-A, br-B, main (HEAD)
```

This indicates that we are "on" branch `main`—running `git status`, we'll see `on branch main`—and since `main` points to `H`, we're using commit `H`.

#### A short sidebar on "using a commit"

To use some particular *branch name*, we run either `git checkout` (in old Git versions) or `git switch` (since Git 2.23).  Git now looks up the branch name, finds the commit it specifies, and tries to switch to that commit and branch.  If that's possible, we are now "on the branch" and we *see* the files *from* that commit.

To make that happen, Git literally *copies the files out of the commit*.  Commit `H` contains a full snapshot of every file—just like any commit—but those files are in that special, Git-ified, de-duplicated form.  So Git *expands* the files into ordinary everyday files.  These ordinary copies go into ordinary folders—Git's files aren't really in folders (this part gets complicated but we can mostly just ignore it)—and now we have ordinary files to do ordinary work with.

*The files you work with, in your working tree, are not **in** Git.*  They were copied *out of* Git.  When you make new commits, you'll store new (de-duplicated) Git-ified copies into Git.  These *won't* be the files in your working tree: they'll be Git-ified, de-duplicated *copies* of the files in your working tree.  So now, at this point, you're free to do *anything at all* with *these* files.  They're not *Git's*, they're *yours*.

All this extra copying is why you have to run `git add` so often.  We'll skip over the details, although they are important: it's the presence of a Git-ified, de-duplicated copy in Git's *index* or *staging area* (two words for the same thing) that makes a file *tracked* and thus go into the next commit.

Anyway, if you check out some *other* commit, Git will have to *remove*, from your working tree, the files from *this* commit, and put in instead the files from the other commit.  We'll see this in action in a moment.  For now, let's just run `git checkout br-A` to get "on" branch `br-A`:

```
    ...--G--H   <-- br-A (HEAD), br-B, main
```

We're still *using* commit `H`, but now we're using it because of the *name* `br-A`.  Since we didn't actually switch *commits*, Git does not do the remove-and-replace-files thing, this time.

#### Making a new commit

To make a *new* commit, we:

- fuss with the files in our working tree;
- run `git add` and/or `git rm` if/as we like; and
- run `git commit`.

The `git add` and `git rm` commands manipulate Git's *index* or *staging area*, which we mentioned in passing above.  This holds the Git-ified copies of files that will go into the *next* commit, and `git add` means *make the staging copy match the working tree copy*.  When we run `git commit`, Git:

- Gathers all the metadata it needs for the new commit: your name and email settings from `user.name` and `user.email`, the current date-and-time, and so on.  This includes the *current commit hash ID*, i.e., the actual hash ID of commit `H`.
- Freezes into a permanent snapshot the (pre-de-duplicated, Git-ified copies of) files that are in Git's index/staging-area.  This will be the snapshot for the new commit.
- Writes out the combined metadata and snapshot, forming a new commit.  The new commit gets a new, random-looking (but not really random) hash ID.  We cannot predict what it *will be* unless we know exactly what files you'll be snapshotting *and* exactly what *time* you'll run `git commit`.  But we'll just call the new commit "commit `I`" for short.

When we look at what happens with the commits, we get this:

```
              I   <--- br-A (HEAD)
             /
    ...--G--H   <-- br-B, main
```

Here's the sneaky trick Git pulled: As soon as Git got the new commit's hash ID, Git *wrote that hash ID* into the *name* `br-A`.  So now `br-A`, the *name* that is, selects new commit `I`.  Commit `H` is not changed at all, but new commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`.  The other branch names don't move either.  The special name `HEAD` remains attached to the name `br-A`, so we're still `on branch br-A`.  But the *last commit* on `br-A` is now commit `I`.

If we repeat this for another new commit, we'll get a new commit `J`:

```
              I--J   <--- br-A (HEAD)
             /
    ...--G--H   <-- br-B, main
```

Note that the files in the snapshot in `J` probably don't match the files in the snapshot in `H`.  That's how we *want* things to work.

We're now ready to start working on branch `br-B` though, so now we switch to it:

```
git switch br-B
```

which results in this:

```
              I--J   <--- br-A
             /
    ...--G--H   <-- br-B (HEAD), main
```

The name `br-A` *continues to point to commit `J`*, but now we're using the name `br-B`, which points to commit `H`.  We've changed commits, so Git pulls out all the commit-`J` files and puts in, instead, all the commit-`H` files.

We now do our work as usual and run `git add` and/or `git rm` as usual.  Then we run `git commit` and Git makes a new snapshot and metadata.  We'll call this new commit `K`—the next letter—although in reality it has some big ugly random-looking hash ID, and we'll draw it in:

```
              I--J   <--- br-A
             /
    ...--G--H   <-- main
             \
              K   <-- br-B (HEAD)
```

When we make yet another commit `L`, we get:

```
              I--J   <--- br-A
             /
    ...--G--H   <-- main
             \
              K--L   <-- br-B (HEAD)
```

Note that commits up through `H` are on *all three branches* right now.  Commits `I-J` are only on `br-A` right now, and commits `K-L` are only on `br-B` right now.  I say *right now* because these branch names *move*.  The set of commits that is "on" some branch is the series of commits that ends at the commit to which the name points, so here, `main` *ends* at commit `H` right now, and therefore that's the *last* commit on `main`.

Git calls that last commit a *tip* commit, as in the "tip of the branch".  That's a useful term because it's quite specific.  We know exactly what a commit is now, and if we pick one out, we know what it has in it.

#### You now have a pretty good idea of what "branch" means

As we can now see, the word *branch* is not very well defined.  Sometimes it means a *branch name* like `main` or `br-A` or `br-B`.  Sometimes it means the final commit *on* the branch.  And sometimes it means *some or all commits findable by working backwards from the tip commit*.  People will say *branch* and mean any of these things, or perhaps even more things (Git has *remote-tracking names*, which some call *remote-tracking branch names* and therefore include in the word "branch").  Try to avoid the word *branch* because it's so fuzzy, but remember that people will say *branch* and you're supposed to figure out what they mean—if they even know what they mean!

#### At last, we can look at merges

Let's take this setup again, though this time I'll leave out the name `main` because it's in the way:

```
          I--J   <-- br-A (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br-B
```

If you run `git merge br-B`, Git must now locate *three* commits.  These three commits are:

- the current or `HEAD` commit, which is really easy to find: that's where we are now;
- the commit you named on the command line: `br-B` is a name for commit `L`, so commit `L` is the "other" commit for the merge; and
- the *merge base* commit.

This last commit, the merge base, is the first complicated part of a merge.  Git finds the merge base on its own for you, so that you don't have to—this was a really important feature back in the early days of Git, where some version control systems *didn't* do that—and we won't go into details about *how* Git finds this merge base.  We'll just describe the merge base a little bit vaguely this way: **The merge base of two commits is the best *shared* commit that's on both branches.**

Here, we're using the word *branch* to mean "commits as found by starting at the two tip commits and working backwards".  We must find some commit(s) that are on *both* branches.  Commit `L` doesn't count because it's only on `br-B`, and commit `J` doesn't count because it's only on `br-A`.  Commits `I` and `K` don't count for the same reasons.  But commit `H` is on *both* branches.  In fact, it's easy to see from this drawing that commits `H` *and all earlier commits* are on both branches.

The *best* such commit is, loosely speaking, the "latest" one "closest to the two tip commits".  That's commit `H`.  So commit `H` is the *merge base*.

#### A merge is about combining work

Git now performs the merge by *combining work*.

We know that each commit holds a full snapshot of every file.  So, in commit `H`, we have a full snapshot of every file as of the form it had at the time you (or whoever) *made* commit `H`.  Commit `I` also has a snapshot of every file, and commit `J` has a snapshot of every file.

Git can figure out what you changed on `br-A` by *comparing* the files in `H` with the files in `J`.<sup>1</sup>  Whatever is different, those are your changes on branch `br-A`.

Meanwhile, Git can do the *same thing* with `H`-vs-`L`.  Whatever is changed from `H` to `L`, that's what they (whoever they are) did on `br-B`.

What `git merge` will do, having done these two comparisons, is *combine the changes*.  In your case, the changes on one side may touch one file `file1.py`.  The changes on the other side may *also* touch that same file.  But on one of the two "sides" of the merge, one side *removed* `file2.py`.  If that was "them", on `br-B`, and if you didn't touch `file2.py` at all, Git will combine *your* changes to `file1.py` with their *removal* of `file2.py` and *retain the removal of `file2.py`.

When you run:

```
git merge br-B
```

Git will find all the changes and combine them, and then attempt to apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot in commit `H`.  That keeps your changes and adds theirs, or, equivalently, keeps their changes and adds yours.  Where your changes and theirs do not conflict, Git will assume that this is the *right result*.

If this is *not* the right result, *you must correct it*.  You have a lot of options for doing this, including running `git merge --no-commit`.  This forces `git merge` to stop with the merge incomplete, even if there are no conflicts at all.

If Git *is* able to finish the merge on its own, *and* you don't *stop* it, Git will go on to make a new merge commit, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br-A (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br-B
```

New commit `M`, the merge, extends the current branch `br-A` in the usual way.  New commit `M` has a snapshot as usual—that's the snapshot Git built by applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot in commit `H`—and metadata as usual as well.  The *only thing that is special about merge commit `M`* is that instead of listing *one* parent, commit `J`, it lists *two:* commit `J` first, and then commit `L` second.

If you *do* choose to use `git merge --no-commit`, Git will *always* stop before making `M`.  You may now make any changes you like and—if needed—run `git add`.  For instance, if Git chose to delete `file2.py`, you can use `git restore` to extract it from commit `J`.  Be aware that if you *do* do this, you need to make a remark about it in your commit message, so that someone else, later, doesn't wonder why Git kept the file, against Git's normal rules.  In any case, when you're done re-arranging the snapshot to go into the final merge, use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to *make* new commit `M`.  Git will make it as a merge commit, with the two parents instead of one.

Alternatively, you can let Git go ahead and make merge `M` on its own, and then restore the missing file from commit `J` and make a new commit `N`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- br-A (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br-B
```

The file `file2.py` will be present in `J`, absent in `M`, and present again in `N`.

Last, if you prefer that `file2.py` not go missing at all, you can check out branch `br-B` and, *before you start the merge*, add a correcting commit that puts `file2.py` back:

```
          I--J   <-- br-A (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L--L2   <-- br-B
```

Now when you switch back to `br-A` and merge, Git will compare `H` vs `J` to see what you changed, and `H` vs `L2` to see what they changed.  Since you put `file2.py` *back*, there's no change to `file2.py` in the `H`-vs-`L2` comparison.  The *combined* changes will therefore *not* remove `file2.py`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git *could* compare `H` vs `I`, and then `I` vs `J`, but in fact it just jumps straight to the end and compares `H` directly to `J`.  A commit-by-commit comparison might help in certain cases, e.g., to handle file renames better.  Git *should* probably have this as an option, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292109/18081892

It is also depending on which sequence you have done on your repo.If the file2.py has been removed from the Branch A and then you merge the branch A, I think the behaviour is the normal one.