# Interactively reverting individual changes between git branches (or in GitHub pull request)?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

I made extensive changes to an open-source project with a large codebase, mostly using an interactive find-and-replace, then filed a GitHub PR and forgot about it.  Two years later, they're taking a new look at the old PR, so I merged the current `main` branch back onto my changes and pushed out the result.

The problem is that in the interim, a lot of the fixes I made were addressed by other commits, but their fix differs from mine in an unimportant way -- whitespace, comment wording, etc.  I want to make it easier to review my PR by reducing the number of changed files, but I don't want to hand copy individual path names for each file containing trivial changes, into something like `git checkout main -- path/to/similar-file.ext`, which would also risk overwriting an important change without realizing it.

Is there a clever command line that will show me each individual *change* (not whole-file-at-once) between one branch (`main`) and another (`my-feature`) with an interactive prompt to keep one or the other, similar to interactive cherry-pick?  I'd also be happy with a solution that uses GitHub's PR interface, or VSCode.

Comment: don't merge `main` into your feature branch, `rebase` your feature branch to current main, fix the conflicts, add the changed files to a commit and file a new PR

Comment: I don't see how `rebase` instead of `merge` makes a difference.  If I've changed 50 files in `my-feature` they're still changed after a rebase.  The point is to step through each change (after the merge or rebase) and decide whether to keep it, or leave it as-is from `main`.

Comment: it keeps the git history clean, then use the `Stage Selected Changes` to stage what you want to commit and revert file for all the other changes

Comment: Maybe I'm invoking `rebase` wrong?  I did `git checkout my-feature; git rebase main`.  There were conflicts, so I resolved them, `git add fixed-file.ext; git rebase --continue`, repeat until rebase finishes.  When would I "stage selected changes"?

Comment: yes, you should now have all the changes you want to be made, because in resolving the conflicts you have selected the `main` branch versions that only had whitespace diffs

Comment: When I ran `git rebase main`, the merge favored my local (trivial) whitespace/punctuation changes and didn't ask me which to use.  That's the whole problem, I guess.

Comment: it should flag any difference on the same lines as a conflict or does git have a setting to ignore whitespace, some files use whitespace (YAML,Python,....) and automatic choosing a punctuation difference is not what I want

Comment: It wasn't strictly whitespace, for example in a JSDoc comment the `main` branch might have had `@returns {string|undefined}` where I had written `@returns {undefined|string}`.  I don't know why the change automatically resolved in favor of `feature-branch`, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I wanted using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355990/26286), as long as I was OK with losing the associated commit history.  In short:

```sh
# my-feature branch has a mix of important and trivial changes
git checkout main

# new name for branch with only selected changes
git checkout -b my-feature-retry

# Use "--patch" flag for interactive prompt for each incoming change from my-feature
git checkout -p my-feature

# answer prompt for each change, uses same interface from `git add --interactive`

# Any change where you answered "Y" will be staged and ready to commit
git status
```