# Unlink commits/Files during creating a Pull request from One branch to other

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos, azure-boards

**There's a challenge!**

I'm working on two projects (`Project1` and `Project2`) within the same code repository (`main` branch). I've made changes to both projects and linked separate work items to each set of changes during my commits.

Now, I only want to push the changes for `Project1` to a different branch (Target branch). However, when I create a pull request, it includes files from both projects.

Is there a way to leverage the linked work items during the push process to only push Project1 changes?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried using cherry-picking, but I'm curious if there's a way to achieve this directly through the linked work items.

Comment: Probably not. Pushing is only supposed to sync the state of your remote branch with the state of your local branch. It is not supposed to change what happens in those commits.

Comment: cherry-picking or, to make it more user friendly (though it's the same thing) choosing commits with `git rebase -i`.... those are the normal ways to do it.

Comment: And that is because commits are cryptographically linked to their parents in a recursive graph.... you can't just push a commit and not include the parents it links to..... well, you could, just for the kick of it, actually create a repo and only copy (by hand) a commit object without anything else.... but git won't like it.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't a way can achieve this directly through the linked work items. It's a good choice to use cherry-picking. Azure Repos provides limited support for cherry-picking, you need to use git command or VS. Also, you can see this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-can-i-selectively-merge-or-pick-changes-from-another-branch-in-git) whether is helpful for you.